# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, ant, rest-client

I am trying to execute rest api using HTTP client in java

I am using ant project so using below dependencies in module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="kv.http-client">
  <resources> 
    <resource-root path="httpcore-4.4.14.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="httpclient-4.5.13.jar"/>
  </resources>
</module>
```

While executing the code I am getting below error. Please let me know what is wrong with this.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/946820#946820) from JBoss community suggests, you should add a dependency to the `javax.api` package:

> You should be able to fix this by adding
>
> ```
>     <module name="javax.api"/>
> ```
>
> to the dependecies section of the `module.xml` for the module
> `org.apache.commons.httpclient`